# Iphone 6 black screen of death?

Tags: iphone

I foolishly let my iPhone 6 rest on my counter in my bathroom while I took a shower. A little while later I went to use my phone and all I got was an illuminated black screen. I plug it in. 10 minutes later I notice it's illuminating, but black screen present.

So I try to hard-reset it. Now all I have is a really black screen that does nothing. BUT I know it's on! It's working (somewhat) because my car's bluetooth picked it up today. So what can I do? I have it sitting in rice. Whether this is helpful or not at this point I am terrified of losing it.

Another dumb thing is I never backed my phone up, like ever.
So if I do take it in and they say they can't fix it, I've just lost everything.

Is there any hope this can be fixed? 2 stores have told me there's little they can do but run diagnostics and see what works and what doesn't.

Comment: & both those stores are about right. The time to be realising a backup would be a useful thing to have is *before* you need it.

Comment: If it appears that it's working just not displaying anything, you can try an app like [Reflector](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/).  It will show a virtual screen on your computer.  You might be able to initiate an iCloud backup by using the virtual screen.

Comment: @fsb That seems like something you could make into an answer!

Comment: Hi George, ya, I should've made that an answer.  I'll add it, thx.

Comment: Can you add more details to the question?

If so, I have two questions for you to answer: What are the two stores you went to? Also, were they official or Apple Certified?

Comment: Just a protip: Rice is bad, and plugging it in is also bad.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just your screen that is not working properly, as it appears from your description, you can use a screen replicator like [Reflector 2](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/).

You can connect your iPhone to your computer and use the screen representation to perform an iCloud backup.

> Reflector is a wireless mirroring and streaming receiver that works great with Google Cast™, AirPlay™ and AirParrot 2®. Mirror your content to the big screen without wires or complicated setups. Play games, watch movies, demo applications or present from the palm of your hand. Even send your screens directly to YouTube for others to watch live.

If your device needs to be replaced, you can then restore your data from the iCloud backup.